# extracting strings from pyspark dataframe column using find all and creating an pyspark array column

Tags: python, pyspark

Extracting strings from pyspark dataframe column using find all and creating an pyspark array column.

Please note we are using pyspark 2.4 and we do not have other functions available

```
Source:
df - main_block column
GENL:20C:SEME//123/1XXXXXX:23G:NEWM:
GENL:20A:TEST1//111/1XXXXXX:20A:TEST2:190A:TEST3:
GENL:22B:ABC//777/1XXXXXX:20C:TESTB:
AMT:19A:SETT//USD65548,33:


Code Used is:
import re
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType

def extract_tags(s):  
    all_matches = re.findall(r':(.*?):(.*?):', s)     
    return all_matches

extract_col_udf = F.udf(extract_tags, ArrayType(StringType()))

df = df.withColumn('col_tags', extract_col_udf('main_block'))

df.show()

Expected Output in pyspark array column:
[
20C:SEME//123/1XXXXXX:,
23G:NEWM:,
20A:TEST1//111/1XXXXXX:,
20A:TEST2:,
19A:TEST3:,
22B:ABC//777/1XXXXXX:,
20C:TESTB:,
19A:SETT//USD65548,33:
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the criteria correctly, you are trying to extract from 2 digits + 1 uppercase character to next colon (`20A:***:`, `19A:***:`).

Your current regex is too coarse that only matching the colon, it can match `:***:19A:` or `:***:***:`.

To narrow down on the match, try this regex instead.

```
re.findall(r'((?<=:)\d{2}[A-Z]:.+?(?=:)).+?', s)
```

Regex explanation

```
(?<=:)\d => lookbehind positive search. Find colon before a digit.
            lookbehind is only for checking and won't be included in a matched result.
\d{2}[A-Z]: => Match 2 digits followed by 1 uppercase letter followed by 1 colon.
.+?(?=:) => lazy match and lookahead positive search. Find the next colon.
            Same as lookbehind, colon won't be included in a matched result.
```

to achieve the final result, use `explode`

```
df = (df.withColumn('col_tags', extract_col_udf('main_block'))
      .select(F.explode('col_tags').alias('col_tags'))
      .select(F.concat('col_tags', F.lit(':')).alias('col_tags')))
```

Result

```
+-----------------------+
|col_tags               |
+-----------------------+
|20C:SEME//123/1XXXXXX: |
|23G:NEWM:              |
|20A:TEST1//111/1XXXXXX:|
|20A:TEST2:             |
|22B:ABC//777/1XXXXXX:  |
|20C:TESTB:             |
|19A:SETT//USD65548,33: |
+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful?  It's a built in pyspark function allowing you to use regex on a column. Added in 1.5.0 so it should be available to you.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html